# Can I bring glass goblets onboard?

Tags: hand-luggage, ryanair

I was gifted some glass goblets by a relative, and I would need to bring them back to my place on a Ryanair flight. Assuming that they fit in my cabin baggage (and probably taking on me the risk that they break), are they allowed onboard? In theory I see no restriction, but if they break (intentionally or not) they develop sharp objects, which are banned by Ryanair (and most probably every other flight company around). So how is the rule usually interpreted?

Comment: Are the goblets new and in a box? The issue may not be the airline but security, and you might have to go through secondary screening. If you are checking a bag, they can survive if swathed in bubble wrap or 'peanuts' and surrounded by clothing.

Comment: In the end I took them and had no problem. However, I did not explicitly declare them.

Comment: I asked about a case with a glass front and I was told to put it in hand luggage, not in hold.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is your start point and destination. 
However, I will get the TSA rule that should be the strictest. Also, I am assuming that the rule to glass goblets is the same to glass cup.

> You may transport this item in carry-on or checked baggage. For items
>   you wish to carry on, you should check with the airline to ensure that
>   the item will fit in the overhead bin or underneath the seat of the
>   airplane.
>
> To help officers get a clear look at your bag and reduce the need for
>   additional screening, we suggest you pack your bag in neat layers
>   (layer of clothes, layer of electronics, layer of clothes, layer of
>   shoes, etc.) and wrap cords tightly around electronics items.
>
> Even if an item is generally permitted, it may be subject to
>   additional screening or not allowed through the checkpoint if it
>   triggers an alarm during the screening process, appears to have been
>   tampered with, or poses other security concerns. The final decision
>   rests with TSA on whether to allow any items on the plane.

Source: [TSA](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=glass)

Comment: Even if  you get as specific as "crystal drinking glasses" it comes back as allowed in carry-on or checked baggage so, I would say yes.

Comment: I presume you mean the TSA rules that would the the most restrictive. Ryanair don't fly in America so,it cannot be the TSA rules that must apply.

Comment: I have taken crystal glasses and decanter as hand luggage through security at Glasgow airport. I was subjected to a bag search as the lead in the crystal made them opaque to the X-rays. As the security officer said "Well, at least you have proof now that its real crystal."